# Refresh the page item after saving the Interactive grid

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2, interactive-grid

After saving the Interactive grid, I need to Refresh the page item (Display only). How to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to "refresh an item". An item value is determined at page rendering time, based be computations, page process, default values or source settings. But it is possible to use a dynamic action of type "Set Value" to set a read only item value.

Comment: Ok, then how to "Set Value" to a read only item value when interactive grid is saved.

Comment: I haven't tried, but I'd say with a dynamic action of type "Set Value", on event "Save (Interactive Grid) ? Have you tried that ?

Comment: Thanks! Koen. Its working with the dynamic action "Set Value" type.